# Event not firing up (onclick)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, onclick

Try changing almost everything(i.e runat="server", single-double colons)
Here is the try:

```
<head runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" >

    function Decide() {

        document.getElementById('l').innerText = "after";

    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <button    onclick="Decide()">Click!</button>
        <asp:Label ID="l" runat="server">before</asp:Label>

    </form>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: View source and see if it indeed has the id="l" - I am not into ASP but should you not register the script too? And change the button to `<input type="button"` too

Comment: You're sure the form doesn't just submit and reload the page

Comment: Tried.. Not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use ClientId of the label
2. Stop post the form , with "return false"

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" >

      function Decide() {

         document.getElementById('<%=l.ClientID%>').innerHTML = "after";
          return false;
       }

    </script>
   </head>

       <body>
         <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <button    onclick=" return Decide()">Click!</button>
               <asp:Label ID="l" runat="server">before</asp:Label>

          </form>
      </body>
   ```

Comment: 3. and the "innerHTML" too.

Comment: a note for you, asp label is created as span or label acordind to "AssociatecontrolId" property, if you set this property then innerText will work smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated html (source code) to check if the generated  for label has the same Id. The Id for the label is the server side Id, not client side. That's the reason why the javascript does not find the element.

Add the ClientId property to your label control (ClientId="l") and check again.

Greetings

Comment: Tried changing to "ClientId". Also tried changing id. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake.

```
document.getElementById('l').innerText = "after";
```

I tried changing "innerHTML" instead of "innerText". And it worked. Thanks all anyway!